# How can I redirect process output (console) to richtextbox?

Tags: c#

what is wrong why is that the richtextbox doesnt get the stream of Process output? theres no text display in richtextbox..

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Process sortProcess;
        sortProcess = new Process();
        sortProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "sort.exe";
        sortProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        // Set UseShellExecute to false for redirection.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        sortProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;



        // Redirect the standard output of the sort command.  
        // This stream is read asynchronously using an event handler.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        sortOutput = new StringBuilder("");

        // Set our event handler to asynchronously read the sort output.
        sortProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);

        // Redirect standard input as well.  This stream
        // is used synchronously.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        // Start the process.
        sortProcess.Start();



        // Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream.
        sortProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        sortProcess.WaitForExit();


        richTextBox1.AppendText(sortOutput.ToString());
    }

    private static void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,
        DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
            sortOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine +
                "[" + numOutputLines.ToString() + "] - " + outLine.Data);
        }
    }
```

so when sort.exe launches, it displays text, i want all those text be displayed also in richtextbox in RealTime (i dont want to wait for the process to exit, and then read all output)

how can i do it? any wrong part of my code? thanks

UPDATE @botz

i added this in my code

```
 private void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,
        DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {

            sortOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine +
                "[" + numOutputLines.ToString() + "] - " + outLine.Data);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(sortOutput.ToString());


    }
```

but it throws this exception

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

Comment: By definition of what a sort does, it is impossible for there to be any output until all the input has been read. So the sort program is a bad example of getting output in realtime.

Comment: Did your issue solve? I too not able to get anything in Console / RichTextBox. What was the approach you followed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WaitForExit() blocks your UI Thread, so you don't see the new output. 
Either wait for the process in a separate thread or replace `WaitForExit()` with something like this:

```
while (!sortProcess.HasExited) {
     Application.DoEvents(); // This keeps your form responsive by processing events
}
```

In your `SortOutputHandler`, you can now directly append output to your textbox. But you should remember to check if you need to invoke it on the UI Thread.

You can check if it's on the UI thread this way in your handler:

```
    if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired) { richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler), new[] { sendingProcess, outLine }); }
    else {
        sortOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + "[" + numOutputLines.ToString() + "] - " + outLine.Data);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(sortOutput.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: thanks botz,, what is this [ Application.DoEvents(); // This lets your  ]

Comment: oops. edited my post. basically it processes clicks, pending repaints (such as your textbox if text was appended) and other events.

Comment: i tried your code,, but i get exception, check my edited post thanks

Comment: tried the new event handler, but still doesnt get text displayed in richtextbox. what could be the problem? all redirections are fine..

Comment: Line 171 in Form1.cs - change sortProcess.WaitForExit() to the first block of code in my post (forgot to include the while when first posting)

Comment: @botz, thanks, can u upload the working code, that displays realtime text in richtextbox? Thanks very much

Comment: no need to. Just tested it, you really just need to replace the sortProcess.WaitForExit() with the first block of code in my post.

Comment: Tnx. Ill try it when im home. For the mean time, did the edited portion made the rictxtbox display realtime output? Tnx so much

Comment: @botz, i tried the new event handler --> http://pastebin.com/WMMdYuEs   but the richtextbox is not updating.. the gui succesfully connects to the server but theres no realtime output generated.

Comment: The handler is not the problem. The problem is the WaitForExit() call. Replace it: http://pastebin.com/KBazyE2D

Comment: already replaced but no text is displayed in richtextbox -->  http://pastebin.com/1bwpB05m

Comment: PS:  this what the output should look like
PS: 
http://i51.tinypic.com/2wc2s9k.png

those text should be shown in richtextbox in realtime.. thanks

Comment: it works. It just looks like openvpn doesn't write to the standard output stream. try calling it without Arguments and you'll see.

Comment: @botz,, theres a problem in the event handler, it gives this error: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Comment: would u mind helping me here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548543/start-a-process-executable-in-resources

Comment: @Lufthansa if you search for  Application.DoEvents() then you will find many comments from experienced Windows programmers saying it is unnecessary, except most of the comments are stronger than that. DoEvents was created for unmanaged VB but VB.Net and C# do not need it.

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Process sortProcess = new Process())
        {
            sortProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"F:\echo_hello.bat";
            sortProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            sortProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            // Set event handler
            sortProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);

            // Start the process.
            sortProcess.Start();

            // Start the asynchronous read
            sortProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

            sortProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

    void SortOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(e.Data);
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Data ?? string.Empty);
        }));
    }
```

[The example you started with](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DIAGNOSTICS.PROCESS.BEGINOUTPUTREADLINE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) was a console application, which doesn't care much about multithreaded access. For Windows Forms when you update a control this has to be done from the main UI thread, which is why `BeginInvoke` is needed. If you want to check rapidly if a handler like `SortOutputHandler` is working properly you can use `System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write*`, which doesn't need `BeginInvoke`.

**EDIT:** `echo_hello.bat` simply echoes the "hello" string:

```
@echo off
echo hello
```

Comment: @sorin,, ive pasted that code in my program.. mind if u take a look -> http://www.mediafire.com/?v1cpelnvzb7x558   when the process starts, my gui starts to hang,, and no running display is running in richtextbox. thanks

Comment: @Lufthansa, that's because the process really doesn't exit (maybe will timeout at some point) for some options in the combobox (I tried with the first one). However, if you use the eighth option in the combobox it works as expected.

Comment: @Lufthansa, given the nature of the process you're calling I think a good measure would be to use `WaitForExit()` with the timeout option and log the timeout event in the RichTextBox in case it happens.

Comment: @Lufthansa, there's no change in the code: as I said before, the process called simply doesn't exit for some servers (maybe they're not reachable) and for this case you should call `WaitForExit(timeout)` where `timeout` is given in milliseconds.

Comment: @sorin, tnx but the server connection is not yet finished (it doesnt matter as of now).  Im trying to get the openvpn.exe output displayed in rich textbox. Any idea? Tnx....

Comment: PS:  this what the output should look like

http://i51.tinypic.com/2wc2s9k.png

those text should be shown in richtextbox in realtime.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to update the ui from another thread, you need to make sure you are on the main ui thread.  In the method check for InvokeRequired.  See [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx)

Comment: , i dont need the input as the program only displays, and it doesnt accept any input from the user.. how can i transfer the output to richtexbox in real time? thanks

Comment: Yeah, I think i see what you are asking now.

Comment: thank you rob, i read that msdn documentation but i dont get how can i use InvokeRequired and where to use it?

Comment: Take a look at this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx

Comment: , i already have the invoke method,, but nothing is displayed :(  http://www.mediafire.com/?v1cpelnvzb7x558

Answer (score 0):

Complete application and source code available from this external link of codeproject :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335909/Embedding-a-Console-in-a-C-Application

This is tutorial of implementation of https://github.com/dwmkerr/consolecontrol.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment I posted to the question, by definition of what a sort does, it is impossible for there to be any output until all the input has been read. So the sort program is a bad example of getting output in realtime. So the following is for anyone in the future that wants to do something like this for console programs in general. The following uses a `BackgroundWorker` to get the output asynchronously and put it into a `TextBox`. A `RichTextBox` could easily be used instead.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    const string Path = @"C:\Windows\system32\sort.exe";
    BackgroundWorker Processer = new BackgroundWorker();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Processer.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        Processer.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        Processer.ProgressChanged += Processer_ProgressChanged;
        Processer.DoWork += Processer_DoWork;
    }

    private void Processer_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader StandardOutput = e.Argument as StreamReader;
        string data = StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        while (data != null)
        {
            Processer.ReportProgress(0, data);
            data = StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private void Processer_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string data = e.UserState as string;
        if (data != null)
            DataBox.Text += data + "\r\n";
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataBox.Text = string.Empty;
        ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path);
        StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process p = null;
        try { p = Process.Start(StartInfo); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error starting {Path}: {ex.Message}");
            return;
        }
        // Get the output
        Processer.RunWorkerAsync(p.StandardOutput);
        // Put the input
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("John");
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Alice");
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Zoe");
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Bob");
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Mary");
        // Tell the program that is the last of the data
        p.StandardInput.Close();
    }
}
```

For the sort program it is not necessary to call ReportProgress until after all the data has been read but this is a more generalized sample.